# MDC-Web: Theme Color for Checkbox

Tags: material-components, material-components-web

How do I set a custom color on a checkbox element in MDC-Web using basic CSS/HTML/JavaScript?

Example: How to make this checkbox background lightblue?

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        :root {
            --mdc-theme-primary: blue;
            --mdc-theme-accent: lightblue;
        }
        .mdc-ripple-surface.mdc-ripple-upgraded.mdc-button--primary::before,
        .mdc-ripple-surface.mdc-ripple-upgraded.mdc-button--primary::after {
            background-color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.08);
        }        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mdc-form-field">
  <div class="mdc-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"
           id="my-checkbox"
           class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"/>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
           viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark__path"
              fill="none"
              stroke="white"
              d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <label for="my-checkbox">My Checkbox Label</label>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:root {
    --mdc-theme-primary: blue;
    --mdc-theme-secondary: lightblue;
}
```

Material Components for the Web now uses the css variable `mdc-theme-secondary` rather than `--mdc-theme-accent` for secondary colours.

This was changed in version [0.18.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0180-2017-08-21)